# Android SQLite rawQuery - How to select multiple rows of a table

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to use rawQuery to return a cursor with a few different rows of data to be passed into it. When there is only 1 argument it works. When there is more than 1 argument it displays the empty ListView state. I believe the issue lies here:

```
// Query for items from the database and get a cursor back. Edited code for clarity:
        recipeCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  course, name, _id " +
                " FROM recipes WHERE _id = ?",
                selectedRecipesSQL);
```

When the code works the selectedRecipesSQL would look something like:

```
String[] selectedRecipesSQL;
selectedRecipesSQL = new String[]{"2"};
```

And when it doesn't work it would be something like

```
String[] selectedRecipesSQL;
selectedRecipesSQL = new String[]{"2 OR 5"};
```

So, to be clear, I can display a single row of the table in my ListView, but if I try to display more than one row of the table then it won't display anything.

One ugly solution which has crossed my mind (but I haven't pursued) is that I need to edit the rawQuery selection statement to read something like:

```
recipeCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  course, name, _id " +
                " FROM recipes WHERE _id = ? OR _id = ? OR _id = ?",
                selectedRecipesSQL);
```

I'd probably use a for loop to generate the correct amount of WHERE "_id = ?" and then use a string array:

```
selectedRecipesSQL = new String[]{"2", "5"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is by passing the possible values of `_id` as 1 string which is a comma separated list like this:

```
selectedRecipesSQL = new String[]{"1,2,3"};
```

and in your query use the operator `LIKE`:

```
recipeCursor = db.rawQuery(
  "SELECT course, name, _id FROM recipes WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || _id || ',%'",
  selectedRecipesSQL
);
```

This works also for just 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    static String multiply__concat_string(String text,String joiner_,int multiple_)
                    {
                        String output="";
                        for(int i=0;i<multiple_;i++)
                        {
                            output+=(text+joiner_);
                        }
                        if(output.length()>0)
                        {
                            output=output.substring(0,output.length()-1);
                        }
                        return output;
                    }
```

Use it like this :

```
selectedRecipesSQL = new String[]{"2", "5"};
                    db.rawQuery("SELECT  course, name, _id " +
                    " FROM recipes WHERE _id IN("+multiply_concat_string("?",",",selectedRecipesSQL.length)+")",
                    selectedRecipesSQL);
```

Comment: Hmmm, this works but I did just also get it working by changing the rawQuery to be:
        recipeCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  course, name, _id " +
                " FROM recipes WHERE _id = "selectedRecipesSQL, null);. This seems much cleaner, simpler and faster, even if it is not using rawQuery the right way. What's the benefit in doing it the "proper" way?